# Modification of counting sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, counting-sort

The Counting sort below sorts elements based on their ASCII value.
The code below works fine but I want to do some I/O modification. The code doesn't take custom input.

I tried to do some changes but getting undefined behavior. My first doubt is why I'm getting undefined behavior. secondly, Please provide me with the code which will make the below code run as expected. The comment portion is what I tried by myself.**I want it to take input from user.**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

#define RANGE 255

void countSort(char arr[])      //void countSort(char arr[],int n)
{
    char output[strlen(arr)];   //char output[n];

    int count[RANGE + 1], i;
    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));

    for(i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= RANGE; ++i) {
        count[i] += count[i-1];
    }

    for (i = 0; arr[i]; ++i) {
        output[count[arr[i]]-1] = arr[i];
        --count[arr[i]];
    }

    for (i = 0; arr[i]; ++i) {
        arr[i] = output[i];
    }
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    char arr[] = "geeksforgeeks";

    countSort(arr);

    cout<< "Sorted character array is "<<arr;

/*
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    char arr[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    countSort(arr,n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout<<endl<<arr[i];
    }
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ripi2 `strlen(arr)` is working fine. But when I'm passing the character array and it's length, there I'm getting random value.

Comment: (@Ripi2 that's implicit.) SO is not a coding service. Describe *what* the code is to accomplish *how. In the code*: comment your code. What did you try to modify, what observation makes you write `getting undefined behavior`?

Comment: @greybeard As I'm giving some input via loop in the main function , when printing the array, expecting it to get sorted is printing some other characters.

Comment: Please format your code consistently. Not only does it help you read and understand it, it also helps others and make it more likely to be read in the first place.

Comment: I ran your code as-is with an online C++ compiler and it sorted fine.  What is the issue?

Comment: This is a one to one copy from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/ No C++ content. Unbelievable that is published in GeeksforGeeks as C++

Comment: (@ArminMontigny you missed `cout <<` …)

Comment: (@MichaelDorgan you probably ran the geeksforgeeks code without issues. era s'q tried to modify it to use a char count and characters read from `cin` …)

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your post. [Paweł Bęza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56995104/3789665) looks spot-on: vote for it if you find it useful, accept it if/when you expect no better. (You can "shift the accept mark to a different answer" later on when that seems appropriate.)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I want this program to take input from user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the OP asked, how to take an input from the user and sort this. And not a predefined string in a given char array.

I will give the answer. But the question is tagged with C++, and I will convert it to C++.

By the way. The code in the question is a one to one copy from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) and tries to code the so called Counting Sort algorithm in C++ that is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Since the code is taken from GeeksforGeeks I unfortunately need to blame user "rathbhupendra" for really bad C++ code. I am truly sorry.

The code is using:

- C-Style arrays
- Variable Length Arrays (Compiler extension. Not C++ compliant)
- strlen
- memset
- `#include<bits/stdc++.h> and #include<string.h>`
- using namespace std
- unusal end conditions in for loops `for(i = 0; arr[i]; ++i)`
- char arrays instead of `std::string`s
- a Macro to define an array size (`#define RANGE 255`)

So, nothing C++.

And now, the answer.

You need to read the string from the user in a variable of type `std::string` with the function `std::getline`.

A std::string can be used like a character array. No difference.

Please see the C++ solution:

**EDIT**

Edited on the comments of MichaelDorgan

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

constexpr size_t AsciiRange = 256;

// Convert signed char to unsigned size_t type.
inline size_t char2sizet(char c) { return static_cast<size_t>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); }

void countSort(std::string& stringToSort)      
{
    std::vector<size_t> count(AsciiRange, 0U);

    size_t i { 0U };
    for (i = 0U; i < stringToSort.size(); i++) {
        count[char2sizet(stringToSort[i])]++;
    }

    for (i = 1U; i < AsciiRange; ++i) {
        count[i] += count[i - 1U];
    }

    std::string output(stringToSort);  
    for (i = 0U; i < stringToSort.size(); ++i) {
        output[count[char2sizet(stringToSort[i])] - 1U] = stringToSort[i];
        --count[char2sizet(stringToSort[i])];
    }

    stringToSort = output;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter a string:\n\n";

    // Get the string from the user
    std::string inputString{};
    getline(std::cin, inputString);

    // Sort it by characters
    countSort(inputString);

    // Show result
    std::cout << "\n\n\nString sorted by characters is:\n\n" << inputString << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps . . .

Comment: Wow!! It helped a lot. But i have some doubt. `constexpr size_t AsciiRange = 256;` what is **constexpr size_t** used for? what is **0U** in `std::vector<size_t> count(AsciiRange, 0U);`. And `count[static_cast<size_t>(stringToSort[i])]++;` **static_cast<size_t>**. Most important of all **from where I can learn to code with such c++ standards**

Answer (score 0):

I geuss by 'getting undefined behavior' you meant *segmentation fault* which *sometimes* occured. The problem lies in this line

```
for(i = 0; arr[i]; i++)
```

instead you should write

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

You can check that in the first case at the end of each loop `arr[i]` is *sometimes* some weird character(this character doesn't belong to the input string) and `count[arr[i]]` for this char returns negative number which produce segmentation fault  here

```
output[count[arr[i]]-1] = arr[i];
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it seems to show exactly what the problem was.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan. You are right, There is an issue, because there are signed chars. I provided an answer in this trhead. But I will update my example code accordingly.    Regarding this answer above ````for(i = 0; arr[i]; i++)```` this will work always for C-Style 0-terminated strings. But it is not nice. If we stick to C, then n would be ````strlen(arr);```` That's better, but no road blocker. But char above 127 can be indeed a problem. BTW the OP did not ask about that but about how to read data dynamically.

Comment: @ArminMontigny No, before edit he asked only about `code which will make the below code run as expected.`. Sentence about `input from user` was added later on. So the main issue was segmentation fault.

Comment: @ Paweł Bęza. I see. Thank's for the clarification.